# Pegar caracteres singularmente em uma cadeia múltipla

Tags: string, regex

Olá, preciso de uma ajuda quanto a uma expressão regular que satisfaça algumas ocorrências de um arquivo de texto.

No caso, preciso de uma expressão regular que encontre ocorrências onde há um número mínimo de caracteres em um padrão. Por exemplo:

Tenho a seguinte string:
`"'C'; 'AEBDCEAB'; 'A'; 'B'"`...

No caso, quero conseguir apenas os caracteres de `"AEBDEAB"`, de modo que eu consiga utlizar cada um *(no caso, o agrupamento é para cada caractere, e não o grupo todo, como em um `/[A-E]/`)*.

Comment: Não consegui entender o que você deseja. Tente colocar um exemplo e, como no caso acima, porque um satisfaz e outro não. Talvez falta a definição de mínimo.

Answer (score 3):

Guilherme, tente assim:

```
var str = "'C'; 'AEBDCEAB'; 'A'; 'B'";
var resultado = str.match("[a-zA-Z]{8}");
```

Utilizei a função **[match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)**.

Isto vai dar uma array onde pode obter o que você quer usando `resultado[0]`. Se quiser cada letra desse grupo pode usar `resultado[0].split('')`

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/cjM23/3/)

---

No caso de aparecer esse grupo várias vezes pode usar:

```
var str = "'C'; 'AEBDCEAB'; 'A'; 'B' 'AEBFCEAB' 'AEBXCEAB'";
var resultado = str.match(/[a-zA-Z]{8}/g);
console.log(resultado); // dá ["AEBDCEAB", "AEBFCEAB", "AEBXCEAB"]
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/hxd7U/)

Comment: Não seria melhor utilizar: `var resultado = str.match("[a-zA-Z]{8}");` para obter apenas o valor correto no array?

Comment: @PauloRoberto, dê a própria resposta ou edite esta. Eu coloquei assim para o caso de haver mais ocorrências na string, senão só dá a primeira.

Comment: Entendi @Sergio. Neste caso devemos disponibilizar as duas opções, :D

Comment: @PauloRoberto, já editei.

Comment: O autor da pergunta disse que quer uma _"expressão regular que encontre ocorrências onde há um número **mínimo** de caracteres em um padrão"_. Nesse caso ao invés de `{8}`, use `{8,}` (ou `{n,}`, onde `n` é o mínimo)

Comment: @NullUserException, verdade, junte isso à resposta...

Comment: Não sei se houve um erro de digitação mas @Guilherme despreza a letra C do resultado desejado. Coincidentemente o caractere 'C' é o inicial. Creio que é necessária uma explicação mais detalhada do que ele deseja.

Comment: Existe alguma diferença entre usar `match("[a-z]")` contra `match(/[a-z]/)`? Ou é só mais um caso da tipagem fraca do js?

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal, não sei responder, mas na MDN diz `A regular expression object. If a non-RegExp object obj is passed, it is implicitly converted to a RegExp by using new RegExp(obj).`

Answer (score 0):

Esta expressão regular casa um mínimo de 8 caracteres, caracteres a-zA-Z:

```
[[:alpha:]]{8,}
```

ou

```
[a-zA-Z]{8,}
```